# Exclude categories from wp_list_categories by category slug

Tags: categories

I'd like to exclude categories from [`wp_list_categories()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) but I want to use the category slug because I do development on a local install where the category ID will be different in production. I got this to work with the following code:

```
$exclcat            = array( 'fp-feature', 'fp-aside-feature' );                               
$output_categories  = array();
$categories         = get_categories( $args );

foreach( $categories as $category ) { 
    if( in_array( $category->slug, $exclcat ) ) {
        $output_categories[ $category->cat_ID ] = $category->cat_ID;
    }
}

$args = array(
    'orderby'            => 'ID',
    'show_count'         => 0, //Use 1 to show the count
    'taxonomy'           => 'category',
    'use_desc_for_title' => 1,
    'echo'               => 1, //Use 0 to not output results
    'title_li'           => '', //creates an <li> entry with text entered here - can be blank
    'exclude'            => $output_categories,
);

wp_list_categories( $args );
```

Is this the proper way to do it or is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a cleaner approach would be to implement an `exclude_slugs` argument for the function, then you can just use the following in your template code:

```
wp_list_categories([
    'exclude_slugs' => [ 'fp-feature', 'fp-aside-feature' ],

    // Other arguments
]);
```

Here's the filter, pop it in your `functions.php`:

```
function wpse_217847_list_terms_exclusions( $query, $args ) {
    if ( ! empty( $args['exclude_slugs'] ) ) {
        if ( ! is_array( $slugs = $args['exclude_slugs'] ) )
            $slugs = array_map( 'trim', explode( ',', $slugs ) );

        $slugs  = array_map( 'esc_sql', $slugs );
        $slugs  = implode( '","', $slugs );
        $query .= sprintf( ' AND t.slug NOT IN ("%s")', $slugs );
    }

    return $query;
}

add_filter( 'list_terms_exclusions', 'wpse_217847_list_terms_exclusions', 10, 2 );
```

Bonus points: no additional db queries needed to first get the slug => ID translations.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of getting *all* categories you could just loop through your excluded slug array and use [`get_term_by()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_by/):

```
$exclude_slugs      = array( 'fp-feature', 'fp-aside-feature' );                               
$exclude_ids        = array();

foreach( $exclude_slugs as $slug ) { 
    $tmp_term = get_term_by( 'slug', $slug, 'category' );

    if( is_object( $tmp_term ) ) {
        $exclude_ids[] = $tmp_term->term_id;
    }
}

$args = array(
    'orderby'            => 'ID',
    'show_count'         => 0, //Use 1 to show the count
    'taxonomy'           => 'category',
    'use_desc_for_title' => 1,
    'echo'               => 1, //Use 0 to not output results
    'title_li'           => '', //creates an <li> entry with text entered here - can be blank
    'exclude'            => $exclude_ids,
);

wp_list_categories( $args );
```

This will make sure we only get terms that we want to exclude.